# spacy-nightly not finishing build

Tags: spacy-3

I am currently trying to use the relation extraction tutorial with custom code to train my own custom relation extraction model on Google Colab. I am trying to install spacy-nightly, but I am getting an unexpected error:

!pip install -U spacy-nightly

Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://us-python.pkg.dev/colab-wheels/public/simple/
Collecting spacy-nightly
Downloading spacy-nightly-3.0.0rc5.tar.gz (7.0 MB)
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 7.0/7.0 MB 25.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
Installing backend dependencies ... done
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: spacy-legacy<3.1.0,>=3.0.0.dev0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from spacy-nightly) (3.0.12)
Requirement already satisfied: murmurhash<1.1.0,>=0.28.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from spacy-nightly) (1.0.9)
Requirement already satisfied: cymem<2.1.0,>=2.0.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from spacy-nightly) (2.0.7)
Requirement already satisfied: preshed<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from spacy-nightly) (3.0.8)
Collecting thinc<8.1.0,>=8.0.0 (from spacy-nightly)
Using cached thinc-8.0.17-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (659 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: blis<0.8.0,>=0.4.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from spacy-nightly) (0.7.9)
Collecting wasabi<1.1.0,>=0.8.1 (from spacy-nightly)
Using cached wasabi-0.10.1-py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: srsly<3.0.0,>=2.3.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from spacy-nightly) (2.4.6)
Requirement already satisfied: catalogue<2.1.0,>=2.0.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from spacy-nightly) (2.0.8)
Collecting typer<0.4.0,>=0.3.0 (from spacy-nightly)
Downloading typer-0.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (21 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pathy in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from spacy-nightly) (0.10.1)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm<5.0.0,>=4.38.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from spacy-nightly) (4.65.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.15.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from spacy-nightly) (1.22.4)
Requirement already satisfied: requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from spacy-nightly) (2.27.1)
Collecting pydantic<1.8.0,>=1.7.1 (from spacy-nightly)
Downloading pydantic-1.7.4-py3-none-any.whl (107 kB)
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 107.9/107.9 kB 14.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Requirement already satisfied: jinja2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from spacy-nightly) (3.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from spacy-nightly) (67.7.2)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging>=20.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from spacy-nightly) (23.1)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0->spacy-nightly) (1.26.15)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0->spacy-nightly) (2022.12.7)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer~=2.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0->spacy-nightly) (2.0.12)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0->spacy-nightly) (3.4)
Collecting click<7.2.0,>=7.1.1 (from typer<0.4.0,>=0.3.0->spacy-nightly)
Downloading click-7.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (82 kB)
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 82.8/82.8 kB 10.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from jinja2->spacy-nightly) (2.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: smart-open<7.0.0,>=5.2.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from pathy->spacy-nightly) (6.3.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: spacy-nightly
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Building wheel for spacy-nightly (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
Building wheel for spacy-nightly (pyproject.toml) ... error
ERROR: Failed building wheel for spacy-nightly
Failed to build spacy-nightly
ERROR: Could not build wheels for spacy-nightly, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Anyone know why this is happening?

I have tried looking into what may be going wrong, and think it might be a dependency issue with the Python version that Colab is using and the spacy-nightly package. Not sure, though.

Comment: Don't use `spacy-nightly`, it's a pre-release version that was used for beta testing, and it's currently 2 years out-of-date. Try the current version of spacy first, and if something turns out to be incompatible with the tutorial, try `pip install 'spacy~=3.0.0'` instead to install the latest patch release of spacy v3.0, the closest version to the older `spacy-nightly`.